# Mongoose save not updating the document date type field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a MongoDB document using mongoose find and then save function. All field values get updated and saved to new ones EXCEPT the field with Date type (default: Date.now)
The code works on my machine but when I run the same code on AWS (ubuntu EC2) the same code doesn't function.

schema ref:

```
var subscriber = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: {
        type : String,
        required :true
    },

    phone: {
        type : String,
        required :true,
        unique: true
    },

    expire: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },

    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

the node.js code snippet below -->

```
var updateMySubscriber = function(bodyToUpdate,cb){
    subscriber.findOne({_id : bodyToUpdate.id}, function (err, sub) {
        console.log(err, sub._id);
        if(err){
            cb(err,null);
        }else{
           if(sub) {
             console.log("Updating subscriber...");
             if(bodyToUpdate.expire )
                   sub.expire = bodyToUpdate.expire;
             if(bodyToUpdate.name)
                   sub.name = bodyToUpdate.name;
             if(bodyToUpdate.phone)
                   sub.phone = bodyToUpdate.phone;

               sub.updated_at = new Date().getTime();
               console.log("+===>",sub);
               sub.save(function (err, done) {
                   if (err) {
                       cb(err, null);
                   } else {
                       cb(null, true);
                   }
               });
           }
        });
```

sample value of bodyToUpdate JSON request ->

```
{ id: '5035e6da6d973c872b038d91',
  phone: '9876543210',
  name: 'alex',
  is_active: true,
  expire: '2020-08-30T18:30:00.000Z',
  created_at: '2016-08-24T05:52:53.440Z' 
}
```

Ideally, the .save function should be able to update the expire field with the newly provided value.

Comment: which field suppose to update on change?

Comment: @MarcelDjaman 'expire' field

Comment: not sure but try to fix `bodyToUpdate.expire` with Date object eg `new Date()` and see what you got

Comment: @MarcelDjaman I tried doing it...it works on my local machine but doesn't work on the ec2 hosted server